# Square movement ignoring on which side it's lying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a small game. So a square is my player, you can only move if you are on the platform. The movement works perfectly but when I grapple to another platform the square rotates and falls on another platform but on the different side. So when I press "w" then it should jump, but instead (F.e if it's lying on its right side) it will go right. So my question is How to move the square ignoring on which side its lying. so no matter on which side the square is lying when I press "w" I want to always jump.
Here is my Move code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PlayerMovementSpeed;   
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Platform")
        {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, PlayerMovementSpeed, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-PlayerMovementSpeed, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate(PlayerMovementSpeed, 0, 0);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?? (It's a 2d game in Unity using C#)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using transform.translate, I would recommend rigidbody2d.addForce as it bases its force calculation on the world rather than the cube. I haven't tested it yet, but it should work. Hope this helps!